# Validations for Zend-form using ini file

Tags: validation, zend-form, ini

```
$aElements[]= new Zend_Form_Element_Text(new Zend_Config_Ini('../application/adxsearch/modules/admin/views/config/adminvalidate.ini', 'user_email'));
```

And adminvalidate.ini

```
[user_email]
name = "user_email"
value = ""
attribs.id = "user_email"
validators.regexp.validator = "Regex"
validators.regexp.options.regex = "/^[\d]{0,20}$/"
```

when i run the application i am getting this error..

> Message:
>   parse_ini_file(../application/adxsearch/modules/admin/views/config/adminvalidate.ini) [function.parse-ini-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Please help me..

reagrds
kiran

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a correct running dir? Seems, that Zend trys to open file while staying in different dir.

All paths given in form of "../path" are relative to current working directory, not to the directory of UserForm.php file.